# Slide Toggle for Android

Tags: android

Anyone know of any open source implementation of a slide toggle for android. The default android toggle([ToggleButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html)) is not pretty. I am looking for anything similar to iOS. I should be able to implement one from scratch. But if anything similar is already available, then i can build on it.

Thanks in advance to the wonderful stackoverflow community.

**Edit1:**
  What I meant by iOS Slide Toggle is UISwitch

[image: ios Toggle Button]

**Edit2:** Just want to summarize the answer. Commonsware provided the clue. I ended up back porting the *Switch* code from  4.0  to2.2.2. Thanks to the open-sourced code, back porting  was not very difficult.  The code is hosted on git hub. http://github.com/pellucide/Android-Switch-Demo-pre-4.0/tree/master/

A screenshot from that project 
  [image: Screen shot]

Comment: I ended up back-porting the 4.0 code to 2.2.2. I also added some new attributes to the widget to adapt to the project that I was working on. Though the look is not exactly same as iOS or Android, it can be easily changed with a drawable.  The project is hosted on github

 https://github.com/pellucide/Android-Switch-Demo-pre-4.0/tree/master/android-switch-demo

Comment: I am sorry I did not see this before, as I just did the same: I backported the Switch class to work with 2.2.  The result is here: https://github.com/BoD/android-switch-backport  - I hope it can be useful, it is slightly different from your own port as it includes the ICS 'standard' drawables.

Comment: Wow! Great job. I also wish I saw this before I skinned the togglebutton. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920709/use-android-4-0-styled-toggle-button/15640365#15640365

Comment: sir, I am having issues with this project,meaning if i use the same resources and everything, the switch appears grey in xhdpi devices. What could i be missing? However if i run ur project in the same device things work well. I am using action sherlock bar too and several values folders . Please help thanks @pellucide

Comment: @Ratatouille Please report the issue on github page. I will be glad to take a look at it.

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118050/how-can-i-style-an-android-switch

Comment: When application is in background and it's going to be resumed it crashed here (android switch demo) 

private Layout makeLayout(CharSequence text) {
        return new StaticLayout(text, mTextPaint,
                (int) android.util.FloatMath.ceil(Layout.getDesiredWidth(text, mTextPaint)),
                Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.f, 0, true);
    }

I guest it's because variables are static. What is the solution

Answer (score 13, accepted):

iOS does not seem to have a "slide toggle", at least under that name, based on a Google search. And, you did not provide an image (or a link to an image) of what you want.

Android 4.0 added a [`Switch`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html) that you might be able to backport to earlier versions. You will see samples of it in the API Demos app on your emulator:

[image]

Comment: This is close. I will have to back port the Switch code. Thanks !

Comment: how did you back-ported it?

Answer (score 15):

you can use the sliding drawer widget in android to have a sliding toggle switch. you just have to "slice" the ios toggle images into3 parts, one for the handle, one for the sliding drawer background and one for the content part. then put an image on top of it like a frame to give you the "round edges"

here's what i've come up with:
XML Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp" >
        <SlidingDrawer
            android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
            android:layout_width="154dp"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ios_retina_toggle_on_full"
            android:content="@+id/content"
            android:handle="@+id/handle"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/handle"
                android:layout_width="54dp"
                android:layout_height="54dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:src="@drawable/ios_retina_toggle_button" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ios_retina_toggle_off" />
        </SlidingDrawer>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ios_retina_toggle_frame" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

ios_retina_toggle_on_full
[image: ios_retina_toggle_on_full.png]

ios_retina_toggle_button
[image: ios_retina_toggle_button.png]

ios_retina_toggle_off
[image: ios_retina_toggle_off.png]

ios_retina_toggle_frame
[image: ios_retina_toggle_frame.png]

and finally a screenshot of how it looked on the emulator on a 3.7 WVGA screen running gingerbread:
[image]

Comment: This is a clever way to do it. I will try that today. However I already took the code from android 4.0 "Switch" and adapted it to work on Android 2.2.x. I managed to add a few extra features like  textOnButton,  and textOutside.

textOnButton- puts the text on the button(the circle) in addition to on the track.
textOutside - puts the text outside the track.

Comment: Can you provide an example or source of that? It would be very useful as i'm trying to do the same..

Comment: @NeTeInStEiN you only need the xml layout for this to work plus the sliced images i already provided. then it's just a sliding drawer class, you can use it's isOpened() method as the "On" state if the value is true.

Comment: @user892771 you went all out, that's really cool, i've put your project as well as BoD's on my watch list. thanks guys!

Comment: couldn't you simply use **2** transparent PNGs, instead of using **4** images?!

Comment: i guess so, but at the time i was answering this question i didn't have enough time to edit the iOS toggle button with transparency. ;)

Comment: Thanks, this works great.  On some screens I get a 1-pixel vertical line to the right of the handle which appears in the "off" state.  It's as if that graphic had a vertical line of transparent pixels on the right side but I don't see it in the graphic.  Any ideas?  Thanks again!

Comment: @Bill it might need some adjustment on the PNGs, it would really help if you use transparent PNGs as Der Golem suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `ToggleButton` specifying your own drawables for its states.

Comment: That could work. But I was looking for that sliding motion from one state to the other. It gives the feeling of physically sliding a switch.

Comment: ToggleButtons don't have the **sliding **effect**

Answer (score 1):

We can try using seekbar with custom drawables and thumb, setting the max value to 1 and min to 0. we can add animations for sliding effect