# Switch View on Gingerbread

Tags: java, android, xml

I've coded an app which uses Switch as a toggler.
When I run it on ICS I have no problems, but when I run it on gingerbread it crashes:

```
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{it.android.smartscreenon/it.android.smartscreenon.ActivityImpostazioni}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #58: Error inflating class Switch
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1768)
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1784)
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #58: Error inflating class Switch
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:212)
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at it.android.smartscreenon.ActivityImpostazioni.onCreate(ActivityImpostazioni.java:43)
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1722)
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     ... 11 more
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.Switch in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/it.android.smartscreenon-1.apk]
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
05-04 11:00:43.261: E/AndroidRuntime(1455):     ... 23 more
```

It looks like Switch doesn't exist on Gingerbread. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: I worked around using a Toggle Button.

Comment: would love to use switch on <ICS as well.  Surely this is possible, possibly using the ICS source code.  It would be great to see it in the android incompatibility library

Answer (score 1):

Use a togglebutton instead. Switches were added in API level 14. Here is the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html).

Comment: Agreed. To make it look like a switch, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920709/use-android-4-0-styled-toggle-button/15640365#15640365