# Styled Toggle Buttons in Android

Tags: android, togglebutton

I was reading the tutorial on Styling the Android toggle button [here](http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/07/sexily-styled-toggle-buttons-for-android/). The author asks us to create the 9patch drawable for both. I have trying to do this all morning, but have not been able to. Could anyone share the images with me, or  tell me where i can get them ?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can find the 9patch drawable tool in the SDK folder in the tools folder.
It's a very useful tool for creating 9patch images, and you should be able to make your toggle button with it

Comment: I have been using that but to no avail. The Toggle off button is fixed and the on part is not displayed on calling  ?

Answer (score 0):

There are links to 9-patches here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15640365/2066079

The ones provided will style your togglebuttons to look like switches (which are only available in v14+)