# Can switch (ToggleButton) for Android 4.0 be used in 2.3

Tags: android, button

Android 4.0 introduces the switch button (a different form of the toggle button). Is it possible through some support library to use this button on a 2.3 platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, there is no simple support library that allows the switch button to be used on 2.3, but there are several suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920709/use-android-4-0-styled-toggle-button).

I was looking for the same things a couple weeks ago, but I decided to just use the CheckBox widget on 2.3 since I didn't want to add unnecessary code for an old API.

One good suggestion in the link I provided is to replace the Drawables of the CheckBox widget with Drawables showing the SlideSwitch. It doesn't slide (just clicks on and off), but it looks better than a CheckBox.

Answer (score 0):

**Easy step ! If you have 2 image- power on / power off, it's easy.**

Make a drawable/togglebutton_setting.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_on" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_off" android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_off"/>
</selector>
```

Add ToggleButton to switch - as background.

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/switch_dark_mode"
    android:layout_width="53.3dp"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:background="@drawable/togglebutton_setting"
    android:textOff=""
    android:textOn="" />
```

**Comment**
switch_on & switch_off are image for power on/off.
  off -- https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBrrz.png
  on --- https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHHJP.png