# How to change background of switch in android ?

Tags: android

I am trying to change background of switch.It is changing but problem is some text is visible.

> [image]

Below is my code

```
  <Switch
    android:id="@+id/switchsubsurf"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:textOff="                "
    android:textOn="                 "
    android:thumb="@drawable/toggle_button"
    android:track="@drawable/toggle_bg" />
```

Comment: Why there is huge space here android:textOff="                "
    android:textOn="                 "??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118050/how-can-i-style-an-android-switch

Take a look at this link.. i think this will of of help.

Comment: try  android:button="@null"

Comment: Hi i tried what u specified but still i am seeing some "0","1" in switch.

Comment: Are toggle_button and toggle_bg custom files??

Comment: they are images which i want to replace

Answer (score 14):

make a drawer folder inside res

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_on" android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_on" android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_off" android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_off" android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="false"/>

</selector>
```

Then do this in xml

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/saveLoginCheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textOn=""
    android:textOff=""
    android:text=""
    android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
    android:thumb="@android:color/transparent"
    android:track="@android:color/transparent"
    />
```

Comment: then do in xml with  <Switch
                        android:id="@+id/saveLoginCheckBox"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textOn=""
                        android:textOff=""
                        android:text=""
                        android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
                        android:thumb="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:track="@android:color/transparent"
                         />

Comment: Upvoted for including the need to set the existing thumb and track transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this answer:

[Use Android 4.0 styled toggle-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920709/use-android-4-0-styled-toggle-button/15640365#15640365)

You can use a 2.2-compatible toggle button and stylize it to look like a switch, or really anythink you want. Just swap out the *.pngs provided in the post.

Not sure why Android went away from toggle buttons in favor of switches when they could have just changed the look and feel of the button. Anyway, I would stick with the toggle button for compatibility sake, especially if you want to change the look and feel of it anyway.