# How to change Width of Android's Switch track?

Tags: java, android

I'm going crazy with this tiny problem. I have a 'switch' Form widget, but no matter how much I try, I cannot make it narrower. Even if I have one character instead of 'ON' or 'OFF', the size of switch remains the same. The 'thumb' becomes small, but it has to be dragged over the same distance as before. Changing the 'layout_width' to a smaller value simply cuts off the remaining track. 'minWidth' doesnt seem to do anything.

Anybody knows how I can do this? Ideally I want just an empty thumb and I'll colour code both thumb to know which is which.

XML code:

> ```
> <Switch
>      android:id="@+id/switch3"
>      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>      android:text="Switch"
>      android:textOff=" "
>      android:textOn=" " />
> ```

I am gettin this: [image]

but I want something like this: 
[image]

Comment: show us your xml code

Comment: android:layout_width="<any smaller amount lower than wrap_content>"

Comment: then the left side is trimmed off. The gap between both sides is still the same. I want the gap in between to be narrower or even overlapping.

Comment: Trimmed off? That's odd. Shrink your parent container and see what happens, or insert padding inside your parent container. It'd be helpful if you posted the XML that you're concerned about.

Comment: I even checked on a blank activity with relative layout containing only the switch widget from above. Still, it is being trimmed off. This stubborn gap between both sides doesnt seem to get narrower at all. :(

Comment: @NeilDA please mark the answer below as Correct if it has solved your problem. It has solved mine. Request moderators to mark

Comment: @alexsummers, I never got to test the answer below because I was done with the app long before. However, I had also used custom thumb and track without any alteration to the width etc to achieve the desired result. I would mark it as correct anyway.

Comment: oh. Actually i'd been struggling with the same problem for a while, and had overlooked the answer below the first time cuz it wasnt marked, might be helpful for others looking for the solution. Thanks :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173590/how-to-change-the-size-of-a-switch-widget

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54420782/7368406

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Set your desired width of switch in the attribute:

```
android:switchMinWidth
```

for example:

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switchVisitAgain"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:checked="false"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:switchMinWidth="56dp"
    android:textOff=""
    android:textOn=""
    android:thumb="@drawable/round_button"
    android:track="@drawable/button_black" />
```

Comment: this trims of the left part of the switch. Any suggestion on how to achieve a symmetric switch?

Comment: yes if you are using the default switch then it only trims right part. I had used this solution for the custom drawables of switch.

Comment: spent almost two weeks figuring out a solution, always kept trying "setminWidth" you are a lifesaver!

PS: switchMinWidth="0dp" is what I used. That way the switch scales according to the drawable

Comment: can't properly set a width smaller than 2x thumbs~ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762490/how-to-change-height-and-width-of-switch-in-android/54420782#54420782

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution. I removed the texts, set the padding of the track and define the `switchMinWidth` properties. This is my xml:

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/theSwitchId"
    android:textOn=""
    android:textOff=""
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:thumbTextPadding="5dp"
    android:switchMinWidth="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Who are using `androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat` need to use

```
app:switchMinWidth
```

Example:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/switch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:switchMinWidth="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:track="@drawable/custom_track"
    android:thumb="@drawable/custom_thumb"
   />
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use `android:track` instead of `android:thumb`.

All my code:

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch_security_tog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:button="@null"
    android:textOff=""
    android:textOn=""
    android:thumb="@null"
    android:switchMinWidth="56dp"
    android:track="@drawable/thumb" />
```