# How to change height and width of Switch in Android

Tags: android, switch-statement

1. I woudld like to fit the switch in 120dp width and 30dp height.
2. Also I want to no text in the thumb but would like to have the thumb cover half of the total width so i want it to be 60dp.
3. Also, I want the height of the thumb to be little less than the height of the switch of the  background could be seen from 3 sides.

I have no idea how to do #3 and for #1 and #2, I tried the following xml, but it is not working:

```
 <Switch
         android:id="@+id/plug_switch"
         android:layout_width="120dip"
         android:layout_height="10dp"
         android:maxHeight="10dp"
         android:layout_below="@id/plug_graph_layout"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:minWidth="100dp"
         android:thumb="@drawable/plugs_button"
         android:track="@drawable/btntoggle_selector"
         android:textOn=""
        android:textOff=""
         android:width="120dip" />
```

could someone please help me with #1, #2 and #3.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173590/how-to-change-the-size-of-a-switch-widget

Answer (score 22, accepted):

add this `android:switchMinWidth="56dp"` and try

```
<Switch
         android:id="@+id/plug_switch"
         android:layout_width="120dip"
         android:layout_height="10dp"
         android:maxHeight="10dp"
         android:thumbTextPadding="25dp"
         android:switchMinWidth="56dp"
         android:layout_below="@id/plug_graph_layout"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:minWidth="100dp"
```

Comment: But this will just make sure that the minWidth does not go below 56dp. I want it to be at 120dp. so how does this help?

Comment: i did, but the point is that my image is larger than 120 dp and hieght is greater than 10 dp. but i want to fix it at 120 and 10 respectively

Comment: can't properly set a width smaller than 2x thumb

Answer (score 7):

here is a small example how to change your swicth width,
 i hope it will help some one..

1)Use ur color for thumb  (color_thumb.xml)

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">


<size android:height="40dp"  />
<gradient android:height="40dp" android:startColor="#FF569BDA" android:endColor="#FF569BDA"/>
```

2)gray color for track (gray_track.xml)

```
shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle"
>

<size android:height="40dp"  />
<gradient android:height="40dp" android:startColor="#dadadada" android:endColor="#dadadada"/>
```

3)Selector for thumb (thumb.xml)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/gray_track" />
<item android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/color_thumb" />
<item android:state_checked="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/color_thumb" />
<item                               android:drawable="@drawable/gray_track" />
```

4) Selector for track (track.xml)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/color_thumb" />
<item                               android:drawable="@drawable/gray_track" />
```

and finally in switch

use

```
     android:switchMinWidth="56dp"
     android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"
    android:track="@drawable/track"
```

Comment: issue is that i do not have colors for background and thumb. i have actual png files. So the png stretches to fit the size of the switch.

Comment: @Sunny why you want to use png files..it takes more memory than shape drawables .and its little bit hard to maintain the state of focus...if u r using nine patch,it wont work,use shape instead

Comment: I am all for drawing. i could if it is just a simple shape like a rectangle. But here the background has a some icon placed on top of it. I cant draw the icon. so i had to use a png.

Comment: @Sunny then calculate the dp,and put png files in all drawables -Xhdpi,hdpi.etc...

Answer (score 4):

```java
final int switchWidth = Math.max(
    mSwitchMinWidth,
    2 * mThumbWidth + paddingLeft + paddingRight);

final int switchHeight = Math.max(trackHeight, thumbHeight);
mSwitchWidth = switchWidth;
```

The code above is method `onMeasure()` in class Switch, set `android:switchMinWidth` can not change the width properly,
the only easy way is that change field `mSwitchWidth` by reflection dynamically:

```java
try {
    Class clazz = Class.forName(Switch.class.getName());
    final Field switchWidth = clazz.getDeclaredField("mSwitchWidth");

    if (switchWidth != null) {
        switchWidth.setAccessible(true);        
        int width = widthWhateverYouWant;
        switchWidth.set(switchClassInstance, width);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, getMeasuredHeight());
        return;
    }
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Do not forget `setMeasuredDimension(width, getMeasuredHeight());`,
because `measuredWidth` of Switch is not base on field `mSwitchWidth`.

I guess it's not difficult to change height since you know how to change width :)

Comment: Thank you! I can't properly set a width smaller than 2x thumbs~

Comment: This definitely works. Always kinda hacky to use reflection, but I really can't see an easier way of achieving this effect.