# How to change width of SwitchCompat thumb

Tags: android, xml, android-switch, switchcompat

My question is about `Android` `SwitchCompat`.

Style that I want to :

[image]

But my switch's style is :

[image]

My thumb's width is something wrong. (Please never mind track size)

This is my xml code :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    app:switchMinWidth="@dimen/_108px"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_108px"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_60px"
    android:thumb="@drawable/switch_thumb_selector"
    app:track="@drawable/switch_track_selector" />
```

`android:layout_width` helps to set width of track, and `android:layout_height` helps to set height of thumb. But I want to set width of thumb. How to set width of thumb?

Comment: set  android:layout_width="wrap_content"

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Thanks but it's not work. And `android:layout_width` is work for width of track :(

Comment: Show your @drawable/switch_thumb_selector code. Thanks.

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726408/switch-button-thumb-gets-skewed

Comment: can't properly set a width smaller than 2x thumbs~ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762490/how-to-change-height-and-width-of-switch-in-android/54420782#54420782