# Android: Is there a way to change the height of switch button?

Tags: android

The switch height looks really small on a tablet. Is there a way, we can increase the height?
If we increase it by giving a value to layout_height, it just add some blank space at the bottom, but the switch size doesnt increase.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173590/how-to-change-the-size-of-a-switch-widget

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try this:

```
android:thumbTextPadding="25dp"
android:switchMinWidth="56dp"
android:track="@drawable/custom_grey_image"
```

Comment: It only increase the width but not the height.

Comment: so you can use drawable and set it.
android:thumb="@drawable/round_button"
android:track="@drawable/button_black"

Comment: So its only possible using a custom image?

Comment: as per my exp.,its only possible using only custome images.I have already find out all solutions.

Comment: I just did some rnd and found that we actually dont need to use android:thumb. We can keep the default and just use android:track with some grey image of height say 50px

Answer (score 3):

The  @dipali answer is righthere is a small example how to change your swicth width,
 i hope it will help some one..

1)Use ur color for thumb  (/res/drawable/color_thumb.xml)

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">


<size android:height="40dp"  />
<gradient android:height="40dp" android:startColor="#FF569BDA" android:endColor="#FF569BDA"/>
```

2)gray color for track (/res/drawable/gray_track.xml)

```
shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle"
>

<size android:height="40dp"  />
<gradient android:height="40dp" android:startColor="#dadadada" android:endColor="#dadadada"/>
```

3)Selector for thumb (/res/drawable/thumb.xml)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/gray_track" />
<item android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/color_thumb" />
<item android:state_checked="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/color_thumb" />
<item                               android:drawable="@drawable/gray_track" />
```

4) Selector for track (/res/drawable/track.xml)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/color_thumb" />
<item                               android:drawable="@drawable/gray_track" />
```

and finally in switch

use

```
     android:switchMinWidth="56dp"
     android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"
    android:track="@drawable/track"
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work for SwitchMaterial. The switch got invisible after this update

Answer (score -2):

You can try to use `android:padding="5dp"` or `android:paddingTop="5dp" and android:paddingBottom="5dp"`

Comment: Nope. That doesnt work! I want to increase size of the switch and not add padding or any margin.