# Android Studio How to change switch size?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button

I make a custom switch button and put it on AS.He his work perfect but how can i change size height and width of this switch button, I want to change it 5/6 times bigger then this [image]

Comment: Try `android:switchMinWidth="100dp"` and `android:switchMinHeight="100dp"`

Comment: Get error: android:switchMinHeight="100dp"
This inspection highlights unknown XML attributes in Android resource files and AndroidManifest.xml

And android:switchMinWidth="100dp" don't change anything

Comment: Sorry it does not work for you. Try this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24725843/5973371