# Android - how to make a switch bigger?

Tags: android, xml, switch-statement

Here's my switch in xml:

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/mySwitch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textOff="OFF"
    android:textOn="ON" />
```

I cannot find a property in `<switch>` to make the switch bigger, what I tried so far:

`android-textSize`, controls the description size that is located right next to the switch, not the switch ON/OFF itself

`android:switchMinWidth`, controls the width of each switch's component (ON/OFF)

I simply want my switch to be bigger, and the text ON and OFF also take effects of the switch getting bigger.

Is there a property I missed?

Comment: You mean the size in the layout? I might be missunderstanding your problem but don't you mean the stuff that `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` are responsible for? `wrap_content` tells the view to take the size that the content needs, if you want more try absolute values (e.g. *60dp*) or `match_parent`

Comment: unfortunately changing layout_width and layout_height to match_parent only marks the area of the switch, the size of the switch itself remains unchanged. If I change both to match_parent, I will have a very small switch in the middle of the screen.

Comment: ahhh ok, thx for clearing that up, I was already wondering if you skipped some crucial part in the android tutorial :D

Comment: Did you figure a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need customize current switcher through replace image files in styles.

<strike>This link</strike> automatically generate needed files, after that you get your own image files, re-draw what you want if needed.

Answer (score 17):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39630516/1448357) solution.

Add these lines to your tag in xml file.

```
android:scaleX="2"
android:scaleY="2"
```

Comment: working fine thanks
but switch icon was blurry any idea to resolve that?

Comment: It makes the switch blurry (it just scales up the rendered image of the switch)