# How to enlarge the Switch widget OFF and ON button in android?

Tags: android, android-widget, togglebutton

I know there is a way on how to enlarge the `switch` widget using customize `drawable` with 2 switching images on it.

But is there a way to enlarge the default switch `buttons` (on/off) of the switch `widget`?. without using switching on/off images.

**Here is the screenshot of my desired output:**

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: What is the use case? Why do you want to enlarge it?

Comment: Please see the edit sir..I have added an image.

Comment: So you want the switch to look like the default Android one, but wider?

Comment: Yup, But not just look like. I want to override the default one to make it wider. if there is a way?..

Comment: I had a look at the Switch source code but could not figure it out, but maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173590/how-to-change-the-size-of-a-switch-widget

Comment: Im gonna try to view that one. They seem had good conversations there. Thanks.