# How to change the height of a switch widget?

Tags: android, xml, widget

I want to have my switch widget larger and so I have to change the height of the switch.

But I have no solution to this.

I looked at this question: [Change height of switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173590/how-to-change-the-size-of-a-switch-widget)

And I made a drawable like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle"  android:width="0dp" android:height="30dp">
    <solid android:color="#FF4444"  />
</shape>
```

Then I setted my switch like this:

```
<Switch
android:id="@+id/sw_trackLiveData"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/tv_liveData"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btn_stoptrip1"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_stoptrip1"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:thumbTextPadding="25dp"
android:switchMinWidth="56dp" 
android:track="@drawable/roundedbutton"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:textSize="20dp" />
```

But it doesnt work. I do something wrong. Can anyone give me an example how to do right? Or can anyone guide me through this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your roundedButton.xml like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <size
        android:height="20dp"
        android:width="56dp" />
    <solid android:color="#FF4444" />

</shape>
```

Comment: I just ran through your example and I was able to recreate your situation. As dato says in his post, the solution is that you have to use the <size.../> element. The android:height="..." and android:width="..." you used in the <shape.../> element aren't valid attributes for <Shape/>

Answer (score 4):

**Change your switch Selector to below in drawable (custom_selector.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item android:state_checked="true">
    <shape
      android:shape="rectangle"
      android:visible="true"
      android:dither="true"
      android:useLevel="false">
      <gradient
        android:startColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:endColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:angle="270"/>
      <corners
        android:radius="20dp"/>
      <size
        android:width="37dp"
        android:height="37dp" />
      <stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="#0000ffff"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
  <item android:state_checked="false">
    <shape
      android:shape="rectangle"
      android:visible="true"
      android:dither="true"
      android:useLevel="false">
      <gradient
        android:startColor="@android:color/white"
        android:endColor="@android:color/white"
        android:angle="270"/>
      <corners
        android:radius="20dp"/>
      <size
        android:width="37dp"
        android:height="37dp" />
      <stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="#0000ffff"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

**and Create Track in drawable (custom_track.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle"
  android:visible="true"
  android:dither="true"
  android:useLevel="false">
  <gradient
    android:startColor="@color/card_background"
    android:endColor="@color/card_background"
    android:angle="270"/>
  <corners
    android:radius="20dp"/>
  <size
    android:width="50dp"
    android:height="26dp" />
</shape>
```

**And in Xml file :**

```
<Switch
  android:id="@+id/switch"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
  android:textOff="OFF"
  android:scaleX="2"
  android:scaleY="2"
  android:textOn="ON"
  android:thumb="@drawable/customswitchselector"
  android:track="@drawable/custom_track" />
```

Answer (score -1):

just change

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to

```
 android:layout_width="200dp"
 android:layout_height="100dp"
```

Comment: I think setting android:layout_width will only affect the width of the text label in front of the switch, not the width of the actual sliding switch. Likewise, setting layout_height adjusts the height of the entire widget, but does not change the height of the sliding switch.

Comment: The question is referring to the entire widget including the switch graphics, not only the outer container.