# Cannot change android Switch style when using Holo Everywhere

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I am having trouble changing the style of a Switch view in my project and can't figure out what I am doing wrong or missing... My project uses holo everywhere.

I can't change the text, the thumb or the track. I've tried applying android:thumb and android:track drawables directly from the xml but nothing changes. Not even the android:textOff and android:textOn have any effect.

I found a great post on how to customise the android Switch view style and looked through all the code but couldn't find anything I was doing wrong:
http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/how-to-use-and-custom-switch-in-android.html

Really not sure what else to try.

Here is the xml code:

```
    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/home_availability_switch"
        style="@style/MySwitch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:textOff="Free"
        android:textOn="Busy" />
```

Here is the style:

```
<style name="MySwitch" parent="@style/Holo.Switch.Light">
    <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/selector_availability_switch_thumb</item>
    <item name="android:track">@drawable/selector_availability_switch_background</item>
</style>
```

Here is the thumb selector 
(these are default system drawables. i have tried with different drawables):

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_pressed_holo_light" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_activated_holo_light" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_disabled_holo_light" android:state_enabled="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_holo_dark"/>
```

Here is the track selector 
(these are default system drawables. i have tried with different drawables):

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_bg_disabled_holo_dark" android:state_enabled="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_bg_focused_holo_dark" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/switch_bg_holo_dark"/>
```

I also found this post [How can I style an Android Switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118050/how-can-i-style-an-android-switch) and follow the instructions but had no luck.

Any one else had a similar experience when using Holo Everywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the switch like this. Need the whole package name in there for it to work.

```
<org.holoeverywhere.widget.Switch
    android:id="@+id/lockSwitch"
    style="?switchStyleOld"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TestSwitch" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: you forgot to add the namespace for the "style" attribute.

Comment: you don't need it for style.

Comment: That was it! Thanks! Spent the whole morning messin about with this. When referencing the Switch view class in the holoeverywhere package as above, the prefix of the styleable properties changes to app:. so app:textOn, app:thumb etc...

Comment: app is only available because i had declared xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.your.package.here" in the parent layout...

Comment: @AswinRajendiran really? weird. are there other attributes that don't need it?