# android:track attibute for Switch doesn't work

Tags: android, android-switch, target-sdk

Example: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118050/how-can-i-style-an-android-switch)

```
android:track="@drawable/switch_bg"
```

Eclipse outputs:

> error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'track' in package
>   'android'

Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

This file `switch_bg` was created.
What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>`android:track` and the corresponding `setTrackResource(int)` method are only available since API 16, you should set `android:minSdkVersion="16"`</s>

UPD Actually what matters is the build target. Select at least API 16 build target in Project -> Properties -> Android