# Change color of Switch in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-theme, android-styles

I'm trying to change the color of my switch in Android. I realize that I will need new 9patches. I went over to http://android-holo-colors.com/ and selected my color and selected (Switch Jelly Bean). To use Switch Jelly Bean I had to use: https://github.com/BoD/android-switch-backport. To import it into my project I had to add:

```
<item name="switchStyle">@style/Widget.Holo.CompoundButton.Switch</item>
```

to my styles, and then in xml I have to use the switch like so:

```
<org.jraf.android.backport.switchwidget.Switch
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Now everything with the switch works fine. Next, I took everything that was output from the android holo color generator and put it into the proper files:

- drawable (2 selector files)
- drawable-hdpi (9patch files)
- drawable-xhdpi (9patch files)
- drawable-xxhdpi (9patch files)

then I added to my xml:

```
<org.jraf.android.backport.switchwidget.Switch
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:thumb="@drawable/apptheme_switch_inner_holo_light"
android:track="@drawable/apptheme_switch_track_holo_light" />
```

but it is still the original blue color. I believe I'm doing everything correctly. Everything compiles (xml, java). Note: I AM importing `org.jraf.android.backport.switchwidget.Switch` in my java also. Any ideas?

Comment: take a look at this thread, explained very well [styling switch in android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118050/how-can-i-style-an-android-switch

Comment: I have looked at that already. Android holo colors generates the proper 9 patch images and the 2 drawable selector files, and they are definitely in there, but not showing up.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> As per [this](https://github.com/BoD/android-switch-backport/issues/19), (direct answer by BoD copy-paste):

- You must not use `android:thumb` and `android:track`, but instead, `app:thumb` and `app:track` And you must add the following to the root of your xml document:

  `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Comment: i try app prefix before thumb and track but it gives error,still it doesn't support thumbtint and tracktint. can you please help. thanks

Answer (score 6):

Easiest way in Android Lollipop and above,

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="MaterialTheme.Light">
    ...
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/color_switch</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

**for androidx.swithcomapact use**

```
                   app:thumbTint="@color/purple_700"
                    app:trackTint="@color/purple_700"
```

Answer (score 2):

to change the color of switch you can use two images

1. green - when switch is ON
2. red - when switch is OFF

now put this file in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blue_checked" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blue_unchecked" android:state_checked="false"/>

</selector>
```

and in the layout XML file use it as below

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/user_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/notif_checkbox_selector"
/>
```

Comment: nothing to do with the question, i dont give negative points just because i cant do it

Comment: Well, it answers the question that would be assumed from the title.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

switch_thumb.xml

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_holo_light" />
        <item android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_activated_holo_light" />
        <item android:state_checked="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_activated_holo_light" />
        <item                               android:drawable="@drawable/switch_thumb_holo_light" />
    </selector>
```

In the layout of the switch:

```
android:thumb="@drawable/switch_thumb"
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be that you need to put

```
style="@style/switchStyle"
```

in your XML as well