# Android switch widget redesign

Tags: android

Is there any way to redesign that switch control in android?
I need to use custom textes on left/right or custom background etc..

[image]

Thanks, Leslie

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118050/how-can-i-style-an-android-switch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look on these links, it will surely help you.

1. http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.com/p/android-switch-button.html
2. [How can I style an Android Switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118050/how-can-i-style-an-android-switch)