# Change App Color

Tags: android, dynamic, colors, color-scheme

Is there a way to replicate the color changing ability provided by [QKSMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.moez.QKSMS) .
It allows a user to select a color and then changes the app color and everything to that color.This is all done dynamically the moment the user chooses a specific color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this cool online tool: http://android-holo-colors.com

This enables you to create many themes for app widgets with your preferred color. You can then change your app theme by saving values for your theme in SharesPreferences or something similar and apply them in onCreate of each activity you have in your app. You can also create the themes easily in styles.xml. For each view, it has its own style with its own attributes so you will need to learn how to edit the theme of each view you want by searching...

Hope that helps.

**Some Examples:**

*ActionBar:*
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

*Buttons:*
https://www.androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=3307

*SeekBar:*
[Android - styling seek bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163215/android-styling-seek-bar)

*Switch:*
[How can I style an Android Switch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118050/how-can-i-style-an-android-switch)

And a lot more... You will have to search for what you want.

Comment: but this would mean i would have to create and store all possible combinations of the widgets with their different colors.Is there a way i could just store the hex values of the colors and then just change colorPrimary and colorPrimaryDark in my theme since all widgets in the app would inherit from that style.

Comment: Well, yes that's what everyone does. Theming in android is kinda hard for some people, but this is the solution... You will get used to it. :)

Comment: Could you provide me with a rough code or some research material to look at,I am rather new at this so its pretty overwhelming.

Comment: @JudeFernandes Updated the answer with some examples. Hope that helps... :)

Comment: Thank You,will give it a go.