# how to style switch widget correctly

Tags: java, android

I've to style Switch in android and found a good resource [here at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118050/how-can-i-style-an-android-switch/10140801#10140801), I've

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/switch_off_2" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/switch_off_2" />
    <item android:state_checked="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/switch_on_2" />
</selector>
```

and finally the Switch widget as

```
<Switch
    android:background="@drawable/btn_bg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

but result is

[image]

I want to know how can I hide the *purple colored* switch from this.

Answer (score 0):

What I assume is

```
 android:background="@drawable/btn_bg"
```

will be

```
 android:thumb="@drawable/btn_bg"
```

Hope it will solve your problem.