# How to change Switch styling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-linearlayout

I am trying to change the styling of Switch, When i add `Thumb` and `Track` properties to the layout, it hides the `Switch` from the layout. If i remove `Thumb` and `Track` from the layout, it displays custom Switch. Kindly guide me how to change `Switch` styling.

```
   <Switch
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/switchNotifications"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingTop="150dp"
        android:text="@string/notification_settings"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:checked="true"
        android:track="@drawable/track"
        android:thumb="@drawable/thumb"

        />
```

**Thumb.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/gray_track" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/color_thumb" />
    <item android:state_checked="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/color_thumb" />
    <item                               android:drawable="@drawable/gray_track" />
</selector>
```

**Track.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="false"  android:drawable="@drawable/color_thumb" />
    <item                               android:drawable="@drawable/gray_track" />
</selector>
```

**ColorThumb**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <size android:height="40dp"  />
    <gradient android:height="40dp" android:startColor="@color/tabAccessoryButtonSelected" android:endColor="@color/tabAccessoryButtonSelected"/>
</shape>
```

**GrayTrack**

```
<size android:height="40dp"  />
<gradient android:height="40dp" android:startColor="@color/tabAccessoryButtonSelected" android:endColor="@color/tabAccessoryButtonSelected"/>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118050/how-can-i-style-an-android-switch

Comment: I dont want to use images, i had checked that answer and used the other approach, it just disappears the switch