# How to create slide switch in android?

Tags: android

I want to create slide switch for example(on/off) currently shows on if i slide to off will enable and also know which status is currently shows pls help me.

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752760/slide-toggle-for-android

Answer (score 0):

Use [Switch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html) and its setOnCheckedChangeListener and a OnCheckedChangeListener(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked), that gets called whenever the switch is touched, and check the value of isChecked to know the state of the switch. This also applies to ToggleButton; check the [Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html) on both of them for more information. (I think Switch is only available from Android 4.0 on)

Answer (score -2):

You can use [ToggleButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html) There is more information about ToggleButton

Comment: ToggleButton shows only one state if we click changes,but i want both on/off should visible and highlight only selected item using slide

Comment: toggle button doesn't have sliding effect.