# Android toggle button custom look

Tags: android, styles, customization, togglebutton

I've been trying to customize the toggle button look but with no success.
Here is how I want it to look like:

[image]

Can someone give me a tutorial?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752760/slide-toggle-for-android

Comment: not what I'm looking for i need something for 2.2

Comment: As CWAC said, Android is opensource, just go into source of 4 and backport the feature you like within your application to 2.X

Comment: ok, but is there a way without using a switch?

Comment: Have a look on this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23358822/how-to-custom-switch-button/33231991#33231991

Answer (score 120):

create toggle_selector.xml in res/drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_on" android:state_checked="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_off" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

apply the selector to your toggle button

```
<ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/chkState"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn=""/>
```

Note: for removing the text i used following in above code

```
textOff=""
textOn=""
```

Answer (score 9):

I don't know if this is the best solution but it worked fine for me:

**1.-** Decide how big do you want the toggle button. In my case width 56dp and height 76dp.

**2.-** Create the icon set 56px-76px for mdpi, 84px-113px hdpi, same for xhdpi and xxhdpi

**3.-** Move the icons in the corresponding drawable folder. In my case 20 icons 5 in each folder, named ic_name1_on, ic_name1_off [...] ic_name5_off

**4.-** Create the following xml files in a new folder called drawable (if it does not exist yet):

- ic_name1_toggle.xml
- ic_name1_toggle_bg.xml
- ic_name2_toggle.xml
- (...)
- ic_name5_toggle_bg.xml

**5.-** In ic_name1_toggle.xml the code must be:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_checked="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_name1_off" />
    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_name1_on" />
</selector>
```

**6.-** In ic_name1_toggle_bg.xml the code must be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:id="@+android:id/background"
         android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
   <item android:id="@+android:id/toggle"
         android:drawable="@drawable/ic_name1_toggle" />
</layer-list>
```

**7.-** Finally in your layout.xml:

```
<ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="76dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:button="@drawable/ic_name1_toggle_bg"
                android:textOff=""
                android:textOn="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to define a custom background for your button.
Take a look at the Developer Guide on customizing a [Button's background](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#CustomBackground).

However, in step Three, Create a new XML file in the `res/drawable/ directory` Use this Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_da"
          android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_nu" />
</selector>
```

The element `android:state_checked="true"` is what defines that state as the checked background.

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Create selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_da" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_nu"/>
</selector>
```

and use it as background for your ToggleButton.

Comment: I've kept trying this but the code shows error or does nothing, could you please be a bit more comprehensive? What exactly do I have to do? I'm kind of a beginner.

Comment: You have to create two drawables (btn_da and btn_nu)