# Style Switch button to achieve flat style

Tags: android

I want to style my Switch button like this:

[image]

Is there a library that achieves this? Or how can I do this?

Comment: you can give a style to toggle button to achieve above effect see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335239/android-toggle-button-custom-look

Comment: Please don't... oh please don't. You want to make your app look like iOS. Then make an app for iOS instead...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found lib that allows to do this and even more
[SwitchButton](https://github.com/kyleduo/SwitchButton)