# Could my drawable be interfering with my button state?

Tags: java, android, button, android-drawable

Right now, I have a radio group as the parent and toggle buttons as the children.

So something like this:

Layout.xml

```
<RadioGroup

                android:id="@+id/toggleGroup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:background="@color/white"
                android:useDefaultMargins="true"

                android:layout_column="0"
                android:columnCount="11"
                android:rowCount="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
>

        <ToggleButton

                    android:id="@+id/number_zero"
                    android:layout_width="34sp"
                    android:layout_height="40sp"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:textOn="@string/number_zero"
                    android:textOff="@string/number_zero"
                    android:layout_margin="5sp"

                    />
        <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/number_one"
                    android:layout_width="34sp"
                    android:layout_height="40sp"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:textOn="@string/number_one"
                    android:textOff="@string/number_one"
                    android:layout_margin="5sp"

                />
</RadioGroup>
</GridLayout>
```

Code snippet in Adapter:

```
ToggleButton one;

one = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.number_one);

 one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        buttonValue = 1;

                        ToggleButton tb = (ToggleButton) view;

                        if(tb.isChecked()){

                            RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) tb.getParent();

                            for(int i=0; i<(radioGroup).getChildCount(); ++i) {
                                View nextChild = (radioGroup).getChildAt(i);
                                if(nextChild instanceof ToggleButton && nextChild.getId()==tb.getId() ){


                                }else if (nextChild instanceof ToggleButton && nextChild.getId()!=tb.getId() ){

                                    ToggleButton tb2=(ToggleButton) nextChild;
                                    tb2.setChecked(false);
                                }
                            }

                        } else{
                            RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) tb.getParent();

                            for(int i=0; i<(radioGroup).getChildCount(); ++i) {
                                View nextChild = (radioGroup).getChildAt(i);
                                if(nextChild instanceof ToggleButton && nextChild.getId()==tb.getId() ){
                                    ToggleButton tb2=(ToggleButton) nextChild;
                                    tb2.setChecked(false);
                                }else if (nextChild instanceof ToggleButton && nextChild.getId()!=tb.getId() ){
                                    ToggleButton tb2=(ToggleButton) nextChild;
                                    tb2.setChecked(false);

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Above is repeated for each button I have. In this example for button zero and one.

Drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item  android:state_pressed="true" android:state_checked="true" >
        <shape>
            <solid
                    android:color="@color/button_selected" />
            <stroke
                    android:width="1dp"
                    android:color="@color/button_selected"  />
            <padding
                    android:left="10dp"
                    android:top="10dp"
                    android:right="10dp"
                    android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item >
    <item>
        <shape android:state_checked="false">
            <solid
                    android:color="@color/number_button_grey" />
            <stroke
                    android:width="1dp"
                    android:color="@color/number_button_grey" />

            <padding
                    android:left="10dp"
                    android:top="10dp"
                    android:right="10dp"
                    android:bottom="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Behavior I want:

I want switch between buttons so that only one button is pressed down at a time. E.g in this case, if I click on button zero, zero will be pressed and button one is not pressed. If I click on button one, button one is pressed and button zero is not. I want the pressed state to be true.

For some reason, if I remove my drawable for my button above, I can easily toggle like radiobutton behavior and when I press on a button, it remains on the pressed state. However, when I apply my drawable, the button does not remain pressed when down. The state changes only if I click on the button and hold the button with my finger. If I remove my finger, it comes back to state pressed = false.

I'm not sure why with the drawable, it's not the behavior I want.

EDIT: Here's a video on the behavior when I change my toggle buttoms to radio buttons and also when I have my toggle buttons. I switch beween radio buttons and the red selection does not stay put. I do the same with the toggle buttons. https://www.dropbox.com/s/9sinptgoucv1hvn/VIDEO0043.mp4?dl=0

Comment: why in your second item, does the shape have the android:state_checked property?

Comment: Just to enforce that to show grey when the button is not selected. Should I remove it?

Comment: each button has a default state. and that item does not need any property set. I don't know if it will work, if you remove it. But it certainly does not help there. Look at the example [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)

Comment: Yeah changing it doesn't help. I still have the same problem. Any ideas?

Comment: @DuZi, I added a short video to see the problem with my app in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="#696969"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/toggleGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:columnCount="4"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:rowCount="1"
        android:useDefaultMargins="true" >

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/number_one"
            android:layout_width="34sp"
            android:layout_height="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:textOff="1"
            android:textOn="1" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/number_two"
            android:layout_width="34sp"
            android:layout_height="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:textOff="2"
            android:textOn="2" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/number_three"
            android:layout_width="34sp"
            android:layout_height="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:textOff="3"
            android:textOn="3" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/number_four"
            android:layout_width="34sp"
            android:layout_height="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:textOff="4"
            android:textOn="4" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/number_five"
            android:layout_width="34sp"
            android:layout_height="40sp"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_style"
            android:textOff="5"
            android:textOn="5" />
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>
```

**button_style.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
               android:endColor="#99BCA259"
               android:startColor="#99BCA259"
               android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
               android:width="0dp"
               android:color="#99515A91" />
            <corners
               android:radius="0dp" />
            <padding
               android:left="0dp"
               android:top="0dp"
               android:right="0dp"
               android:bottom="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_focused="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
               android:endColor="#99BCA259"
               android:startColor="#99BCA259"
               android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
               android:width="0dp"
               android:color="#99BCA259" />
            <corners
               android:radius="0dp" />
            <padding
               android:left="0dp"
               android:top="0dp"
               android:right="0dp"
               android:bottom="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_checked="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
               android:endColor="#99BCA259"
               android:startColor="#99BCA259"
               android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
               android:width="0dp"
               android:color="#99BCA259" />
            <corners
               android:radius="0dp" />
            <padding
               android:left="0dp"
               android:top="0dp"
               android:right="0dp"
               android:bottom="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_enabled="false">
        <shape>
          <gradient
             android:endColor="#99454545"
             android:startColor="#99454545"
             android:angle="270" />
          <stroke
             android:width="0dp"
             android:color="#99454545" />
          <corners
             android:radius="0dp" />
          <padding
             android:left="0dp"
             android:top="0dp"
             android:right="0dp"
             android:bottom="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item>        
        <shape>
            <gradient
               android:endColor="#99454545"
               android:startColor="#99454545"
               android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
               android:width="0dp"
               android:color="#99454545" />
            <corners
               android:radius="0dp" />
            <padding
               android:left="0dp"
               android:top="0dp"
               android:right="0dp"
               android:bottom="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**MainAcitivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements OnClickListener{
    ToggleButton tb1, tb2, tb3, tb4, tb5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tb1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.number_one);
        tb2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.number_two);
        tb3 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.number_three);
        tb4 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.number_four);
        tb5 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.number_five);

        tb1.setOnClickListener(this);
        tb2.setOnClickListener(this);
        tb3.setOnClickListener(this);
        tb4.setOnClickListener(this);
        tb5.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ToggleButton tb = (ToggleButton) v;


        RadioGroup llLayout = (RadioGroup) tb.getParent();

        for(int i=0; i<((ViewGroup)llLayout).getChildCount(); ++i) {
            View nextChild = ((ViewGroup)llLayout).getChildAt(i);

            ToggleButton cb2=(ToggleButton) nextChild;

            if(nextChild instanceof ToggleButton && nextChild.getId()==tb.getId() ){
                //cb2.setChecked(false);
            }else if (nextChild instanceof ToggleButton && nextChild.getId()!=tb.getId() ){
                cb2.setChecked(false);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

You can [download my git repo.](https://github.com/iamsarker/android-apps/tree/master/ToggleButtonCustom)

Comment: All I did was change my drawable to yours and it works. That is very strange. Could you tell me what was wrong with my drawable? So that I can learn what I was doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Nothing.. You just look into my button_style & onClick view... To study just debug this..