# Android: Multiple selectable buttons

Tags: java, android

I've recently started to build android apps, and I wanted to know if it's actually possible to make a selectable button in android like the image in the link below ?

https://lh4.ggpht.com/ouHPcTcFzsdYrTU09pStGBicxgX_cki613g5Eq3loYCh2TOXzqpfeyWnOdlLuc8eNS0=h900-rw

I'm trying to make a list of numbers that you can do multiple checks, however, I'm not sure if I must use a check box or some other widget. It would be great if I can hear some tips from the pros here!

Comment: Go with Ravi's answer he is right

Comment: Just make checkbox to all and set value and when ever you want click value just check checkbox is clicked or not ...

Comment: @Ravi you know if you are using button then you must have to use click event with array so better approach is use check boxes as per my opinion.

Comment: I will try it , but I wonder if there is some helpful example or tutorial on google that can help a noob like me ?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what logic you want to have. Are there any logical connections between those numbers? Any conditions?

You could also use a `ToggleButton`:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html

Styling:
[Android toggle button custom look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335239/android-toggle-button-custom-look)

Then there is the question of how many buttons do you want to have? Perhaps a variable amount? Then you could use a `GridView` with `ToggleButton`s.

Also there are possibilities to use `RadioButton`s, it's up to you.

Comment: Thank you, I want to make multiple buttons like  like about 31. I want to make them selectable with clicks . But the problem is that I want a number in the middle of those buttons.

Comment: "About 31" sounds like a variable amount. Perhaps it's better to use a GridView with whatever component of your choice. With a `ToggleButton` you can have text centered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:button="@drawable/button_change_view"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:button="@drawable/button_change_view"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:button="@drawable/button_change_view"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:button="@drawable/button_change_view" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:button="@drawable/button_change_view" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

button_change_view.xml is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/location_hide"
      android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/location_show"
      android:state_checked = "false" />
</selector>
```

Using this you don't need to maintain button state , checkbox maintain by itself.

Comment: I'm trying to do your sample, but, if I want to make the checkbox itself like a number in the middle of the button like the image , how can I do it ?

Comment: Just use the images of numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,... and apply these images on checkbox ,You don't need to take button ,you can do your work only with checkboxes