# Change the image background of the button on clicked and bring it to original state when clicked again

Tags: android, button

I have a array of buttons in my class as below :

```
private static final int[] idArray = {R.id.bt0,R.id.bt1,R.id.bt2,R.id.bt3,R.id.bt4,R.id.bt5,R.id.bt6,R.id.bt7,R.id.bt8,R.id.bt9,R.id.bt10,R.id.bt11,R.id.bt12,R.id.bt13,R.id.bt14,R.id.bt15,R.id.bt16,R.id.bt17,R.id.bt18,R.id.bt19,R.id.bt20,R.id.bt21,R.id.bt22,R.id.bt23,R.id.bt24,R.id.bt25,R.id.bt26,R.id.bt27,R.id.bt28,R.id.bt29};
private Button[] bt = new Button[idArray.length];
```

and have added an image background in my xml as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/btnew2"    android:state_selected="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btnew1" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btnew"></item>    
  </selector>
```

Now, when i press a button the background image is changed (btnew1.gif) and is back to normal when released.
I want the color to be changed (it will be a different image, btnew2.gif) when a button is clicked and should return to original color (btnew.gif) when clicked again.

something like `state_clicked` if something is there like that.

PS: I checked other answers here, but most of them were color changers in java class only and what i am looking for the background image to change(to btnew2.gif) when **clicked** and be back to original image (btnew.gif) when **clicked again**.

please suggest suitable solution.

Comment: You can do it programatically, but wouldn't it make more sense using a `ToggleButton`?

Comment: Yes as Niels said it would make more sense using design modified `ToggleButton`. check out this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335239/android-toggle-button-custom-look

Comment: actually i have also set a `TextView` onClick of that button which shows and hides after a few seconds. Is that possible using `ToggleButton` ?

Comment: Yes, it is:ToggleButton is-a TextView so it has all the methods of TextView (setOnClickListener is actually from View). I posted a simple sample of usage.

Comment: I used a ToggleButton as suggested, but the text on toggle button is showing as ON and OFF whereas my setting of the text is not showing. Toggle Button.setText(null) is not working too.. how to turn off the toggle button text ON and OFF

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by making your own custom button.

```
Class MyButton extends Button implememts OnClickListener{

Public MyButton(....){
......
this.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@override
Public void onClick(....){
....toogle bg for this button.....

}

}
```

This is not the exact code....but an abstract idea how you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

As Niels Masdorp mentioned, you can do it with `ToggleButton`.

This works because there is a state identifier called `state_checkable`, similar to `state_clickable`, which works together with the `Checkable` interface. `ToggleButton` implements this interface. You can also create your own widgets implementing this interface, for example extending `CompoundButton` (abstract).

---

**Example**

Use the button in xml:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/toggle_bg"
    android:textOn="On"
    android:textOff="Off"/>
```

Define the background in xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/red" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue"/>
</selector>
```

See also:

- The `Checkable` [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Checkable.html).
- A [tutorial](https://chris.banes.me/2013/03/22/checkable-views/) on custom checkable widgets.