# How can I integrate this toggle switch in my app?

Tags: android

Image: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/MIOoHQ2WRn-UF_v__izFJWm9BsqxGqhbJ85EdbJ29MVHOKp-6w4NWdKTIxHVoJxozOVJ=h900-rw
I need a toggle switch just like this in my android app. What other ways can I go for except using 2 buttons or [this](https://github.com/BelkaLab/Android-Toggle-Switch) repo.

Comment: hi. easy to implement it. You can use a image than set toggle state by two bacground image (one for normal state one for changed state like off and on )

Comment: Just change the color of button on onclick!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android toggle button custom look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335239/android-toggle-button-custom-look)