# Drawing rectangle shape with two buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, shapes

I'm trying to draw this shape including 2 buttons one for patient and other for doctor how can i do something like that ?
[image]

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335239/android-toggle-button-custom-look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are lot of ways to do this, I did it using `shape` and this is the output

[image]

You've to create a `oval_left.xml` and `oval_right.xml` and then create two `Buttons` and apply these `backgrounds` to them.

This is the `oval_left.xml`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="40dp">
<solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>

<corners
    android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
    android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
</shape>
```

And this is the `oval_right.xml` is the same but changing the values and color

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="40dp">
<solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>

<corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topRightRadius="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

Hope it is what you are looking for.

Also if you want to check the full code take a look at this repository : [shapeovalandrectangleview](https://github.com/joancolmenerodev/shapeovalandrectangleview)