# Android Unlock like Swipe Gesture

Tags: android, animation, swipe, gesture

How can I have something like Emulator Swipe to unlock Gesture? What I want is Animation where user will drag a circle left or right and base action on Whether it was dragged left or right. How can this be achived? Something similar to Unlock shown in image below.

Thanks,
Umesh

[image: Emulator Swipe to Unlock gesture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have found one sample solution. Suggestion for similar good libraries is welcomed.
https://github.com/nadavfima/GlowPadView

Answer (score 0):

there is a open source solution for you- https://github.com/pellucide/Android-Switch-Demo-pre-4.0 , hope will help. Good luck.

Comment: Or directly to SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752760/slide-toggle-for-android

Comment: This is a good example when we need toggle kind of solution. In this case I'm looking for Three modes. No Action at center and Left swipe and right swipe to do some action. More lick Simple Phone unlock gesture or Pick the Phone gesture etc.