# Custom switch in Android with text in track

Tags: java, android, xml, uiswitch

I have a custom switch. I want the text (on/off) to be in the track and not in the thumb.

I was thinking of setting a selector with text in drawable and setting it as track of the switch. But I cannot set text in a shape. Any ideas how I can do this?

I also want to add some padding to the track, I dont want the thumb to touch the track.
This is kind of how I want it to look:

[image: I want the switch to be kind of like this]

This is the shape of my track:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"
android:visible="true"
android:useLevel="false">
<corners
    android:radius="20dp" />
<size
    android:width="48dp"
    android:height="21dp" />
<stroke
    android:color="#bfbfbf"
    android:width="6dp"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Switch off screenshot**

[image]

**Switch on screenshot**

[image]

**Switch on image**

[image]

**Switch off image**

[image]

**Thumb image**

[image]

**switch_on_off.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/on_switch"/>
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/off_switch"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/off_switch"/>
</selector>
```

**xml code**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/switch_compat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    app:track="@drawable/switch_on_off"
    android:thumb="@drawable/on_switch_active"/>
```

Try above code and let me know if you find any error.....

Comment: This is possible but i dont have the specific images for my design. I made the design drawable without text. All i need is to add the text.

Comment: Well AFAIK, setting a text in track is not possible, refer this link, may be it could sort out your query:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34765660/custom-android-switch-track-animation

Comment: I am accepting this answer as it is the best so far