# Custom Swtich button Android

Tags: android, slider, switch-statement

I have a question regarding the Android Switch button. Does anyone know how to customise it so looks something like :

[image]

I have found out how I can replace the circle with a custom image using android:thumb= but still not sure how to increase the width of the entire button so it fills up most of the screen width and also add a text on top of it. Also need to add some offset for the thumb just like on the image. Can I achieve this by using the Switch or I have to implement the whole thing myself ?

Comment: https://github.com/kyleduo/SwitchButton

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Slide Toggle for Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752760/slide-toggle-for-android)

Answer (score 1):

Use following to achieve

```
<Switch
                    android:id="@+id/th"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:thumb="@drawable/apptheme_switch_inner_holo_light"
                    app:track="@drawable/apptheme_switch_track_holo_light"
                    app:textOn="@string/switch_yes"
                    app:textOff="@string/switch_no"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    />
```

Create a xml named colors.xml in res/values folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="red">#ff0000</color>
    <color name="green">#00ff00</color>
</resources>
```

In drawable folder, create a xml file my_btn_toggle.xml:

```
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@color/red"  />
        <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@color/green"  />
    </selector>
```

and in xml section defining your toggle button add:

```
android:background="@drawable/my_btn_toggle
```

to change the color of textOn and textOffuse

```
android:switchTextAppearance="@style/Switch"
```